# Jquery Ajax not sending data to php server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

This will be an easy one for you, but after ages of looking online I can't find a solution, or at least one I'm understanding.

**result** and **users** variables both alert correctly.
The **data** contents shows empty - why?

How should I be inserting these two variables into data ?

(also if it is right - how do I view the data content without going into server side)

Thank you in advance.

```
        var result = result.text;
        var users = localStorage.getItem('user');
         alert("1");
               $.ajax({
   url:'********',
   method: 'POST',
   data: {user: users, serial: result},
   dataType: "text",
   contentType: "application/json",
   success: function(data){


       alert (data);
       alert(users);
       alert(result);
```

Comment: Include server side code also

Comment: It's just the sending part at the mo - I want to know exactly what's being sent before being handling it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code `alert(data)` will refer to the `data` returned by the server. Not the `data` of your ajax request.

[`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) takes a `settings` object as its parameter. It's a set of key/value pairs that configure the Ajax request. `data` is just one of the keys of the object you are passing to the `$.ajax()` method.

To simplify your code, this is what is happening:

```
// this is what you're sending to the server
var dataSentToTheServer = {
    user: users,
    serial: result 
}

// creating an object where data, url, success etc are keys.
var settings = {
    url:'api/method',
    method: 'POST',
    data: dataSentToTheServer,
    dataType: "text",
    success: function (dataSentFromTheServer) {
        alert(dataSentFromTheServer); // this argument will have the data returned by your server
        alert(dataSentToTheServer); // data which was sent *to* the server
        alert(data); // doesn't exist
    }
    ....
}

$.ajax(settings);
```

Comment: Okay - thnks - what would be the best way of viewing the data key contents  in that case?

Comment: @MarkD sorry I didn't see the `data` in your success callback. I updated the answer accordingly. In your `success` callback, `data` will refer to the data sent by the server.

Comment: ok thanks v much for that. I'm not completely following the answer. How can I view exactly what is sent, so I can handle it in php? I'm not sure how it will be delivered. In php I have  $u1 = trim($_POST['user']);
$duid = ($_POST['serial']); - would this be correct. The server is not responding - If I can see the fields I could figure it out

Comment: @MarkD  This code means, `{user: users, serial: result}`: you are simply creating an object with 2 properties. Updated the answer on how to get the data sent *to* the server

Comment: Okay! I did as you said (in regards to viewing the going to server data)- and the response i got is [object Object] - any idea why looking at my code?

Comment: `alert` will display only simple string, number or boolean values. If you want see objects, replace the alert() code iwith: `console.log(dataSentToTheServer);` You can see the object in your browser's console. (Press F12)

Comment: By the way, you don;t even have to hit the server to see what object you're sending to the server. Just below the `var dataSentToTheServer = { }` block, add  `console.log(dataSentToTheServer);`

Comment: Great! Seems to be all okay - my final follow up question is on php this would be correct to define the dat right? $u1 = ($_POST['user']);
$duid = ($_POST['serial']);

Comment: @MarkD sorry. No hablo `php`. I am more of a `.net` and javascript person :D

Comment: haha no problem - you've been tons of helps- thanks ever so much :)

Comment: @MarkD on a related note, doing `console.log()` every time you want to check some value is not efficient.  You should learn how to debug javascript using chrome dev tools. Search online and you'll get a lot of resources. [Here's  a good video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KbEx0s06VLs).